# Android TextView/EditText generated dynamically

Tags: java, android

In my app i generate TextViews/Edits dynamically during the execution. I also have a TableLayout so each set of TextEdit/TextViews will be on a new row. I want to use the row number (1...N) as a sort of ID to identify each set of textEdit/TextViews (Example, row 1 will have TEdit1, Tview1, row 2 will have TEdit2, TView2..etc).

I have functions that are called on the onchange of each tEdit. For instance, TEdit 1 changes the value of TView1 when the onChange method is called. The function is set up so that i can pass the TView id and it changes it properly. My problem is, i dont know how to use a variable as the tView id. The function takes for parameter, among others, the rowId (1, 2, 3..etc) so i want to know if there's a way to set up a variable like this:

```
String VariableName = "tEdit" + i; (i is the rowId that its passed through as a parameter)
```

And then use it for something like this:

```
MyActivity.VariableName.setText("Change proper text");
```

Obviously, that one doesnt work. I have done some research and i've seen something like getIdentifier, but i've had no luck implementing that one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't use an array of Textviews instead of trying to define custom name based on row number  etc?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shobhit! I tried that and its all working perfectly and its a much more clean/convenient way. Thanks. Im not sure if this qualifies as an "answer" for my question, but i'd accept it if you'd post it as such ^_^ .

Comment: Glad it helped Oscar. I've put it as answer just in case anyone has the same issue as you in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of `Textview`'s instead of trying to define custom name based on row number etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your question maybe you can find useful "Tag" property. I mean that when you dynamically add your new row to the table you can simply add a tag identifier to this new row with his index position inside the table

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setTag(indexPosition);
```

So, when you need to know the position of the current row you'll simply need to call

```
int position = tr.getTag();
```

I hope that this was your question!